# Ipython Bokeh Scatter Plot Marker Size after Zoom

Tags: zooming, ipython, scatter, bokeh

When using bokeh `scatter` function with the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bpl
bpl.output_notebook()
x=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
y=np.sin(x)
bpl.scatter(x,y)
bpl.show()
```

I can use the  `wheel zoom` and `box zoom` tools to zoom into the plot, and the markers keep a fixed display size. If instead I explicitly set the marker (glyph) size, like in the following code

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bpl
bpl.output_notebook()
x=np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi,100)
y=np.sin(x)
bpl.scatter(x,y,radius=y/10)
bpl.show()
```

the marker size scales accordingly to the zoom scale. How can I set explicitly the marker size and keep at the same time a fixed display size independently of the zoom scale, as it is the standard behavior of mpl3d?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give the plot a `size` instead of a `radius`. By default, `size` is in screen space units, and `radius` is in data space units.